# Need id in url from js

Tags: javascript, html

I need a script that fetch id from javascript into an url

For example: [https://google.com/youtube[id].mp3](https://google.com/youtube%5Bid%5D.mp3)

**javascript currently**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // FETCHING DATA FROM JSON FILE
  $.getJSON("https://api.omny.fm/orgs/56ccbbb7-0ff7-4482-9d99-a88800f49f6c/programs/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/clips/",function(data) {
     
      $('#table').html(data.Clips[0].Id);
    });
});
```

**html currently**:

```
<html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://traffic.omny.fm/d/clips/56ccbbb7-0ff7-4482-9d99-a88800f49f6c/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/<p id="table">/audio.mp3" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>

  <script src="./script.js"></script>



    </html>
```

i hope someone can help me out to get this working :)

thx.

tried multiple things to get id into url but not working

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: i need the id that i get from the output "table" into a meta redirect src.
(example: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=youtube.com/5456567/[id]/audio.mp3" />

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very unclear, but I assume what you're trying to do is fetch the JSON data, then append it to a table.

The first reason things aren't working is likely because your HTML is invalid. Specifically right here:

```
<!-- Why are you trying to embed a p tag into a link? -->
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://traffic.omny.fm/d/clips/56ccbbb7-0ff7-4482-9d99-a88800f49f6c/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/<p id="table">/audio.mp3" />
```

The second issue is that you're using the jQuery `.html()` method, which actually just sets the `innerHTML` of an element. This is dangerous, and you should not do this (especially with fetched data).

```
// This is not good for many reasons
$('#table').html(data.Clips[0].Id);
```

Also, why are you using jQuery in 2023? DOM APIs are modern and extensive nowadays. jQuery is nothing but an abstraction on top of them. Here's a solution I believe will help you.

```js
const URI = 'https://api.omny.fm/orgs/56ccbbb7-0ff7-4482-9d99-a88800f49f6c/programs/a49c87f6-d567-4189-8692-a8e2009eaf86/clips/';
const tableBody = document.querySelector('table > tbody');

const createCell = (content) => {
    const cell = document.createElement('td');
    cell.textContent = content;
    return cell;
};

const createRow = (id, title) => {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    row.appendChild(createCell(id));
    row.appendChild(createCell(title));
    return row;
};

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', async () => {
    // Use the native "fetch" API to fetch the data.
    const res = await fetch(URI);
    // Convert the data to JSON using the ".json()" method.
    const json = await res.json();

    // Loop through all of the clips in the received array.
    for (const clip of json.Clips) {
        // For each clip, add a new row to the table.
        tableBody.appendChild(createRow(clip.Id, clip.Title));
    }
});
```

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: as first thx. But i need the latest / newest id into the src of meta redirect. like: youtube.com/2323/[Here the id[/2343.mp3

Comment: @AndorBird Where are you fetching YouTube links?

Comment: Just an example